# Type of recursive calling generic lambda expression in C++14

Tags: c++, recursion, lambda, c++14

What is the type of the lambda expression in (1) ?

Why can this code compile?

```
#include<functional>
#include<iostream>


int main() {
    std::cout << 
        [](auto&& f0,auto&& a0){return f0(f0,a0);}
        (
            [](auto& f,auto&& a)->int{ return (a>1) ? f(f,a-1)*a : 1; }, // (1)
            5
         )
         << std::endl;
}
```

I think that infinite recursion is caused by type inference for lambda expression (1) in this code.
I think that `auto& f` is replaced to a type name such as `std::function<int(std::function<int(std::function<int(......)>)>)>`.

Please point out my mistake.

Comment: Since you've explicitly mentioned the return type of the lambda the compiler doesn't have to look through the path of the recursive call `f(f,a-1)`. You'd have a problem if you removed the `->int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First mistake: `std::function` is a type unrelated to any lambda.

A lambda is an anonymous type with an `operator()` and a few other known properties.

`std::function<R(Args...)>` is a type erasure class for copy construct, destroy and invoke with `Args...` and return `R`.  It can be constructed from a lambda, but is not otherwise a related type.

As you cannot name the type of a lambda, using a `std::function` to store it is common.  The lambda is not a `std::function` however.  `std::function`s have nearly unavoidable overhead from their type erasure and polymorphism: lambdas lack any polymorphism, which makes it really easy for the compiler to understand what `()` does at the point of invocation.

In your case you have two lambdas.

Your first lambda is:

```
[](auto&& f0,auto&& a0){return f0(f0,a0);}
```

This looks like a form of y-combinator, or a variant, used help with recursion.  The `operator()` in this case has signature:

```
template<class F0, class A0>
auto operator()(F0&&,A0&&)const
-> std::result_of_t<F0&(F0&,A0&)>
```

roughly.

A more useful version (in my opinion) is:

```
[](auto&& f0){
  return [f0=std::forward<decltype(f0)>(f0)]
    (auto&&...args) {
      return f0(f0, std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    };
}
```

which takes an `f0`, stores it, and invokes it with any arguments passing `f0` first.  This lets you bind the recursion 'out of sight'.  Making the inner lambda `mutable` is optional (depends if you want to invoke in a `const` context)

Anyhow, the next lambda:

```
[](auto& f,auto&& a)->int{ return (a>1) ? f(f,a-1)*a : 1; }
```

has an `operator()` signature of:

```
template<class F, class A>
auto operator()(F&,A&&)const
-> int
```

You then pass an instance of the second lambda to the first, plus an argument, and it calculates `n!`.

The types deduced by the `template` operator `()` do not depend on the types that the arguments themselves deduce, so there is no infinite type deduction problem.  The return type of the inner lambda is hard coded to `int`, so you don't have to deduce what `()` recursively returns to know it returns `int`.

If you want to store the first lambda in a `std::function`, however, you are going to be disappointed.  `std::function` cannot erase a `template operator()`: it can only erase a fixed signature, and a `template` member is a factory of methods, not a method itself.

However, remember my better version of y combination above?

Call your first lambda `g`, your second `h` and my lambda `y` and the lambda my lambda returns `z`.

Then `g(h,x)` = `y(h)(x)`  -- and `y(h)` can be stored in a `std::function<int(int)>` no problem.  We hide the part of the recursion that basically requires a recursive type signature, which `std::function` does not support<sup>1</sup>.  What is left, while it has a `template operator()`, can be bound to a simple signature.

---

<sup>1</sup> note that you could write `std::function` to support recursive signatures, like `std::function< std::vector<SELF_TYPE>(int) >`.  You can see how this might work with how `boost::variant` works with recursive variants.

Answer (score 1):

From [expr.prim.lambda], emphasis mine:

> The
>   lambda return type is `auto`, **which is replaced by the *trailing-return-type* if provided** and/or deduced from
>   return statements as described in 7.1.6.4.

You provide a *trailing-return-type*, that is the `->int` in your code, so no type deduction has to happen. The return type is just `int`.

However, even without the `->int`, you can still get your function to compile if you just provided a `if` statement instead of using the conditional operator:

```
auto f = [](auto& f0, auto&& a) {
    if (a <= 1) {
        return 1; // this *must* be the first return case.
    }
    else {
        return f0(f0, a-1) * a;
    }
};

std::cout << f(f, 5) << std::endl; // prints 120
```

This case, and only this case, fits one of the rules as above mentioned in §7.1.6.4 [dcl.spec.auto]:

> If the type of an entity with an undeduced placeholder type is needed to determine the type of an expression,
>   the program is ill-formed. Once a return statement has been seen in a function, however, the return type
>   deduced from that statement can be used in the rest of the function, including in other return statements.
>   *[Example:*
>
> ```
>  auto sum(int i) {
>      if (i == 1)
>          return i; // sum’s return type is int
>      else
>          return sum(i-1)+i; // OK, sum’s return type has been deduced
>  }
> ```
>
> *—end example ]*